# Unique "splitting fields" for infinite polynomials

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, symmetric-polynomials

When creating the splitting field of a polynomial we can without loss of generality assume it has constant coefficient $1$ and splits as $\prod_{k=1}^n(1-z_kT)$. The splitting field is obtained by adjoining $z_k$s and Vieta tells us that $a_k=(-1)^ke_k(z_1,\cdots,z_n)$ where $a_k$ is the $k$th coefficient of the polynomial and $e_k$s are the elementary symmetric polynomials.

Form $R$ as the quotient of $K[Z_1,\cdots,Z_n]$ by the relations $a_k=(-1)^ke_k(Z_1,\cdots,Z_k)$. The ring $R$ will not generally be a field, but every residue field of $R$ (quotient by a maximal ideal) will be a splitting field for $f$ over $K$ (since they will be extensions of $K$ in which $f$ splits generated by these very roots of $f$, the images of $Z_1,\cdots,Z_n$ in the residue field).

Suppose $f(T)\in 1+T K[[T]]$ is an infinite polynomial with constant coefficient $1$. Form $R$ as the quotient of $K[[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]]$ by the relations $a_k=(-1)^ke_k(Z_1,Z_2,\cdots)$ again. Will all residue fields of $R$ necessarily be isomorphic?  What about iso via $Z_i\mapsto Z_{\sigma(i)}$ for some $\sigma\in{\rm Perm}(\Bbb N)$?

---

Thanks to discussion with Lubin, I see I need to be more explicit about what $K[[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]]$ is supposed to mean. After toying with some possibilities, I think $\varprojlim K[Z_1,\cdots,Z_n]$ what I want, where the projection maps are evaluation at $0$.

Comment: What, again, is the expansion of your “infinite polynomial”? More precisely, in terms of your infinite set of variables, what is the coefficient of $T$ therein?

Comment: @Lubin $f(T)$ is a polynomial in $1+TK[[T]]$ with $k$th coefficient $a_k\in K$. The variables $Z_1,Z_2,\cdots$ make no appearance here as they are part of constructing a "splitting field" of $f$.

Comment: Sorry not to be clear enough. What is $e_1(Z_1,Z_2,\cdots)$?

Comment: It is $Z_1+Z_2+Z_3+\cdots$ (and similarly for the other $e_i$). The power series I am allowing in $K[[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]]$ can have infinitely many appearances of any number of variables.

Comment: That is an infinite sum, which is undefined and meaningless without some notion of convergence.

Comment: @Lubin Indeed, and there is a notion of convergence in the completion of $K[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]$ at the maximal ideal $(Z_1,Z_2,\cdots)$, just as there is a notion of convergence in $K[T]$ completed at the max ideal $(T)$, no? Or is $K[[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]]$ supposed to mean the direct limit $\varinjlim K[[Z_1,\cdots,Z_n]]$? If so, what I am talking about is $\varprojlim K[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]/(Z_1,Z_2,\cdots)^n$, where we are using the definition $K[Z_1,Z_2,\cdots]=\varinjlim K[Z_1,\cdots,Z_n]$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13535/discussion-between-lubin-and-sea-turtles)